# How to use mailgun api in Dreamfactory

Tags: php, angularjs, api, mailgun

I want to send emails from Dreamfactory's Angular Application using PHP Mailgun API.

Big question for me is how can I set PHP's mailgun script into Dreamfactory as I'm new in Dreamfactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add Mailgun as a remote web service API in DreamFactory. More info on how to set up a remote web service is [here](http://community.dreamfactory.com/t/examples-on-connecting-to-web-services/71).

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your reply. I couldn't find the place where I can put my PHP code of mailgun. Is there any specific tutorial about put php code in dreamfactory and connect with the app?

Comment: Hey Dhaval, looks like you got in touch with support. I was suggesting no need for the Mailgun PHP script. You'd just set up a secure connection to the Mailgun REST API in DreamFactory (i.e. your Mailgun API creds and any required headers / params) and call the Mailgun API directly from your client application. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Thanks Ben, Can you give me more information or any example how can I make mailgun secure connection in Dreamfactory? and one more thing that is it possible to put PHP code in dreamfactory(its for another task)

Comment: There are a few examples. Check out this blog post which shows how to add remote API credentials and make API calls from your app http://blog.dreamfactory.com/blog/bid/326051/Adding-a-Remote-Web-Service-to-Your-DSP. Also check out this example of exposing a remote API with Swagger (this optional step enables you to easily consume the remote API from DreamFactory's SDKs for Javascript, iOS, Android, etc.) http://blog.dreamfactory.com/tutorial-angular-and-rest-made-simple. If you still need help, send an email to support@dreamfactory.com.

Comment: On your other question, DreamFactory currently supports server-side scripting with Javascript. We will add other languages like PHP, Python, and Ruby in the future (probably in version 2.0 coming out later this year).

Answer (score 0):

Just a (very late) followup on this in case other DreamFactory users are interested. DreamFactory has since added Mailgun support to the platform. You can learn more about it [in the docs](http://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/Tutorials/Connecting_to_Email_Services#Mailgun_Email_Service).